# Linux red-hat5.4 + awk file manipulation

Tags: awk

how to match PARAM (param=name) word in file.txt and print the lines between

NAMEx and NAMEy, via awk , as the following way :

if PARAM  matched in the file.txt , then awk will print only the words between the close NAMES strings while PARAM is one of the names

remark1 PARAM can be any name as Pitter , Bob , etc.....

remark2 awk will get PARAM=(any name)

remark3 we not know how many spaces we have between (# to NAME)

```
 more file.txt

 #     NAMES1

   Pitter 23
   Bob 75 

 #  NAMES2

   Donald 54
   Josef 85
   Patrick 21  

 #         NAMES3

   Tom 32
   Jennifer 85
   Svetlana 25

 # NAMES4
```

examples ( regarding file.txt contents )

```
 In case PARAM=pitter then awk will print the names to out.txt file 

 Pitter 23
 Bob 75 


 In case PARAM=Josef then awk will print the names to out.txt file 


 Donald 54
 Josef 85
 Patrick 21  


 In case PARAM=Jennifer  then awk will print the names to out.txt file 


 Tom 32
 Jennifer 85
 Svetlana 25
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `RS` of awk would be helpful in this case. see the test below:

**testing with example**

```
kent$  cat file
# NAMES1

Pitter 23
Bob 75 

# NAMES2

Donald 54
Josef 85
Patrick 21  

# NAMES3

Tom 32
Jennifer 85
Svetlana 25

# NAMES4

kent$  awk -vPARAM="Pitter" 'BEGIN{RS="# NAMES."} {if($0~PARAM)print}' file               


Pitter 23
Bob 75 

kent$  awk -vPARAM="Josef" 'BEGIN{RS="# NAMES."} {if($0~PARAM)print}' file                


Donald 54
Josef 85
Patrick 21  

kent$  awk -vPARAM="Jennifer" 'BEGIN{RS="# NAMES."} {if($0~PARAM)print}' file             


Tom 32
Jennifer 85
Svetlana 25
```

note, there are some empty lines in output, because they existed in your input. however it would be easy to remove them from output.

**update**

if you have spaces between # and NAMES, you can try:

```
awk -vPARAM="Pitter" 'BEGIN{RS="# *NAMES."} {if($0~PARAM)print}' file
```

Comment: how to update your awk if between # to name I have one or more spaces for example 4 spaces or 10 spaces , how to ignore this? ( see also my update question )